# JavaFX MenuItem display bug

Tags: javafx

My first question here so I hope i can describe my problem correct.

What im facing right now is that i want to display a contextmenu for some entries of a JFXTreeTableView. Therefore i created a new cellFactory called "ProjectTreeItemWithContextMenuTreeTableFactory" which handles the creation of the contextMenu based on mouseReleasedEvent and displaying it.

Due to i dont have 10 reputations i cant post images but as an example what isnt working i try to describe it. If i open the contextmenu it will get displayed at the correct position. When hovering over a menu entry the menuItems will get displayed, but not rendered right next to the menu. 
There can be some times a huge gab between the menuItems and the menu whic hwas hovered....
What i noticed is, that this problem will only occur when hovering for the first time over the menu. If hovering for the second time over the menu while the contextMenu stays open, everything will get displayed correct.

```
private class TreeTableCallback extends TreeTableCell<T, ProjectTreeParentItemFX> {

@Override
protected void updateItem(ProjectTreeParentItemFX item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (item == null || empty) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
        setContextMenu(null);
    } else {
        this.setOnMouseReleased(evt -> handleMouseReleased(evt, item));
        setText(item.getDisplayText());
    }
}
```

Adding menus and menuItems to the contextMenu and showing the menu.

```
private void handleMouseReleased(MouseEvent evt, ProjectTreeParentItemFX item) {
if (evt.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY)) {
    setContentOfContextMenuBasedOnType(item); 
    contextMenu.show(getTreeTableRow(), evt.getScreenX(), evt.getScreenY());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Indeed. Not abbreviating when choosing type names is a good idea, but what you're doing here is excessive...